# How can I clear the canvas screen?

Tags: java, android

Here is my code for the activity main

```
package com.example.dell_7560.experiment6;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new TouchScreen(this,null));
    }
}
```

Here is the touch screen code

```
package com.example.dell_7560.experiment6;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class TouchScreen extends View {

    private Paint paint=new Paint();
    private Path path=new Path();
    public TouchScreen(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context,attributeSet);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(6f);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    }
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawPath(path,paint);
    }
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(eventX,eventY);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                path.lineTo(eventX,eventY);
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now the app works as follows:
Touch the screen.
Drag the finger (it creates the red light)
Untouch the screen, the red line creation stops.
Till here it is cool.

My doubt is, how can I clear the content in the ACTION_UP event?
i.e. on untouching the screen, the screen should be as good as new.

Comment: In the `ACTION_UP` `case`, call `path.reset();`.

Comment: You can also use `canvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);`

Comment: Thanks Mike M, it works.

Comment: SripadRaj, I can't use canvas, if I create an instance then I need to initialize it. I can't initialize it dude, and it's, not a static function (drawColor) so I can't refer it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mike M mentioned,

`path.reset()` works in `ACTION_UP` case
It clears the screen i.e. canvas when I lift up my finger/touch.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is tell the view that it's invalid on ActionUp (you do this). Then it will automatically call onDraw again. The trick then is to not draw anything. All you need to do is either clear the path, or set a variable that will cause the draw routine to not draw. The background always clears anyway, so all you need it to not draw the path after the invalidate.